# check ip address of a linux server to upload the file

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ftp

I am working on a linux server remotely. Are there any command that can allow me to figure out the IP address of this linux server, so that I can ftp some files to this server.

Comment: maybe `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the remote machine is directly connected to the internet:

```
hostname -I|cut -f1
```

otherwise, one of these:

```
wget -qO - http://whatsmyip.me/
wget -qO - http://ipinfo.io/ip
wget -qO - http://ipecho.net/plain; echo
```

In all cases, must be run on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `IP`:

```
hostname -i
```

`IP` along with `hostname`:

```
host $HOSTNAME
```

Comment: This will actually just get the internal IP address.